# Keeping a semi-linear git history where some feature branches cannot be rebased?

Tags: git, git-branch, rebase, branching-and-merging, git-flow

I have the following situation:

- The teams want to keep a linear git history so they are enforcing rebase and squash.
- We have some feature branches with a long lifetime (months even) with multiple devs working on them. They cannot be rebased because it would really complicate things when the other devs try to merge their work to those feature branches.
- These feature branches must be kept up to date by merging the main branches into them.
- Once the feature branch is ready to be merged the only way to keep the linear history seems to be squashing the entire thing. Squashing months of work from several people. Uhh.

Something tells me this is not the best solution. I'm also not a fan of spaghetti flow but I think there is a way to keep a semi-linear history where the large feature branches get merged without all the fuss.

It should be something that all developers can comfortably follow, without any 'hacky' strategies that might confuse juniors.

Any ideas?

Comment: git was designed to work with branches and easily handled them.
Spaghetti flow as you said, is just the representation of your way to work, why hide this.
squashing and rebasing is quite a lie about has happen

Comment: There is nothing wrong with branching and merging. Insisting in a linear history is short-sighted.

Comment: Unfortunately some developers insist on linear history, and I can also see their point because it's hard to keep track of a spaghetti history

Comment: When I hear "semi-linear history", I think of a rebased branch that is merged in with `--no-ff`, which creates a nice looking up-to-date "bubble" in the graph that would have fast-forwarded had the merge commit not been forced. Is that what is being done for branches that can be rebased? (I'm asking because that is slightly different than "The teams want to keep a linear git history...")

Comment: Regarding: "We have some feature branches with a long lifetime (months even) with multiple devs working on them." Is that an exception to the rule, and how many devs are typically sharing the branch? Are the merges into the shared feature branch in the context of a PR with a code review, or do they all just merge locally and push?

Answer (score 0):

> They cannot be rebased because it would really complicate things when the other devs try to merge their work to those feature branches.

True, as long as the feature branch is not ready to be merged.
But:

> Once the feature branch is ready to be merged the only way to keep the linear history seems to be squashing the entire thing

That would *then* the time to rebase that feature branch, in order to preserve that linear history.

And you would create a new feature branch for the developers to go on working.

Comment: Yep I just realized that interactive rebase can actually get rid of the merge commits created during the process. However some commits need to be cherry-picked if conflicts would arise, I'm not sure if they can cause any side effects

Comment: @LucaSaraCzudar It should not, but you still need to test it out to be sure.

Comment: @LucaSaraCzudar Yes, rebasing instead of discarding history is the way to go. And speaking of testing, I highly recommend running [git-test](https://github.com/mhagger/git-test) on the rebased branch (as well as also all the way from the beginning when the feature branch was created).